# Couchdb database-per-user design document management

Tags: couchdb

I am evaluating Couchdb for a web application where there would be many users. If I use the database-per-user model, presumably the design documents in every database will all be identical. I have not found any mention of 'global' design documents acting upon multiple databases, or of any tools to make it easy to change the design docs across all user databases. How is this handled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup continuous replication between a template database that contains all your design documents. So whenever you change the template database, user's database gets updated.

Comment: So replication is not just for server-to-server syncing, but can be used for operations within a Couchdb instance?

Comment: Sure, you can do local replications as well as remote replications.

Comment: How feasible is this for 500.000+ databases? (Remember db_per_user)

Comment: I wouldnt recommend continuous replications for that much databases. For that specific use case, you can probably trigger a manual job (external process) that updates design documents in each database. Also, its often cheaper to have scheduled single shot interval instead of having continuous replication.